# Users Table automatically deleted in Aws Server

Tags: mysql, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I deployed my project on aws server. I don't know why my user's table gets deleted automatically after a few days. I noticed every time only the user's table was deleted. the same code as the server on my local machine also on my personal AWS server working fine. I don't know what's happing there. I mentioned the technology I am using: Laravel, PHP, PHPMyAdmin, AWS Ec2, and cronjob(this cronjob only updates the status for orders only every 10 minutes).

If anyone knows this solution let me know, please.

Comment: One quick fix would be to create a new DB user and remove the `DELETE TABLE` permission from it and let Laravel production use it. If Laravel is doing so, you wil get an exception (and if you are tracking exceptions with a 3rd party app), you will see where is that happening and eventually when. But have in mind that if you run a migration that deletes a table, you will not be able to do so, this is just for debugging purposes

Comment: Are you using Elastic Beanstalk or an auto-scaling group? These will replace the entire server periodically. If you're using these, your database should be off-instance, probably in RDS.